# Java error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and taking the course *Algorithm*, which is provided by Princeton. I follow an example of book: *BinarySearch* in page 9.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch 
{
    public static int rank(int key, int[] a)
    {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
    while (lo <= hi)
    {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if      (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
        else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
        else return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        int[] whitelist = in.readAllInts();
        Arrays.sort(whitelist);

        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) 
        {
            int key = StdIn.readInt();
            if (BinarySearch.rank(key, whitelist) == -1)
            StdOut.println(key);
    }
}
```

However when I compile the file, console reminds me that

```
NPP_EXEC: "java_Compile_Run"
NPP_SAVE: G:\java\binarysearch\BinarySearch.java
javac -encoding UTF-8 "G:\java\binarysearch\BinarySearch.java"
Process started >>>
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)

==========编译成功后开始运行==========
java -cp "G:\java\binarysearch;D:\Program Files\java\jdk\lib\algs4.jar"    "BinarySearch"
Process started >>>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:22)
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

I don't know what is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:22)
```

There is no program mistake, I think. Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: in which line do you have error

Comment: Are you asking what an array index out of bounds exception is? Or are you asking what is casuing it? Or both? Also, @Abdelhak the error is in line 22

Comment: @Abdelhak It can generate a java class. So I think there is no error is each line...

Comment: @AshwinGupta Both I want to know. Thank you for pointing out this.

Comment: @gaoxinge Okay so peter and thilo covered your solution. Ill explain the array exception. `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is essentially exactly what it sounds like. In java, arrays are initalized staticly (most of the time). Upon their creation a certain amount of elements are allocated for it. You cannot try to store something in an element greater then what you have allocated the array for. So for example: `int[] bob = new int[1];` if I try `bob[1] = 3;` than I will get the exception.

Comment: what's In in = new ...

Comment: @Abdelhak he is using a command line arg and I think he isn't specifying it ever. Since he isn't exception handling either its causing an issue.

Comment: Try to post " In " class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main` method expects command line arguments to be given when you start the program.

```
In in = new In(args[0]);
```

Comment: @gaoxinge also, just to clear up here, remember, java runs the main() method which runs the rest of your code. Main takes the argument of a String array named args[]. The contents of this array are also known as command line arguments. When you run the code through cmd you need to specify args[] for it to use. Remember, java indexing starts at 0 so the first arg you give is 0, second is 1, etc. Here is an example run, `java myProgram.class "argument0", "argument1"`. Now in the code if I use `System.out.println(args[0]);` Ill get `"argument0"`

Answer (score 4):

My answer is just here to clear some things up. Take this as an adddition to the other two.

> **What is an** `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

**See this for the official definition:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

**My definition:**

`ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is essentially exactly what it sounds like. In java, arrays are initalized staticly (most of the time). Upon their creation a certain amount of elements are allocated for it. You cannot try to store something in an element greater then what you have allocated the array for. So for example:

```
int[] nums = new int[1]; //allocate nums to have only 1 element (remember indexing starts at 0)
nums[1] = 0;  //this will throw Array index OOB exception
```

> **Why does the code throw** `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

This is because java runs the `main()` method which runs the rest of your code. Main takes the argument of a `String` array named `args[]`. The contents of this array are also known as command line arguments. When you run the code through cmd you need to specify `args[]` for it to use just like you'd specify arguments for any other function call. Remember, java indexing starts at 0 so the first arg you give is 0, second is 1, etc. Since you aren't specifying any arguments at all, your are acessing elements that don't exist. Here is an example run done correctly: (without the quotes I believe)

```
java myProgram.class "argument0", "argument1"
```

Now in the code if I use

```
 System.out.println(args[0]);
```

Ill get `"argument0"`

If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, this may be a bit different. For Eclipse specifically, click on the "Run" menu, then "Run configurations". Then click the arguments tab, then specify your arguments. For multiple args, use a comma to separate.

Answer (score 1):

An *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* means that you tried to access an element outside the array (ie, something that doesn't exist). Here, you tried to access it on this line:

```
In in = new In(args[0]);
```

so, you need to fix your input to the program because it would appear the args[] array isn't being populated.

Comment: How do I fix my input to the program in CMD? Can you give an example of this?

Comment: @gaoxinge look at the comment I posted on Thilo's answer.